# Trying to link tabs from main menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tabs

On my website I have a page called "Company". It has several tabs that contain information. When I click on them on "Company" page, everything works like it should. But the problem occurs when I'm trying to link them on my main menu. I have menu item "Company" that has sub-menus "About us" , "History" etc.
My goal is that for example when I click on "History" it leads me to the "Company" page and the History tab is open. But it doesn't work (the default "About us" tab is always open).

When I'm on the "Company" page and select "History" from the sub-menu, it actually opens the "History" tab for a second, but after the page reloads itself, the "About us" tab is open again. I have tried removing the checked="checked" but then all the tabs are closed.

I suspect that my JS function is missing something but I can't figure this out.

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">

   <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabfive" checked="checked">
   <label for="tabfive" id="fifth-tab">About us</label>

   <div class="tab">
     // About us content
   </div> 

   <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabsix">
   <label for="tabsix" id="sixth-tab">History</label>

   <div class="tab">
      // History content                                 
   </div>

   ........

</div>
```

JS

```
//  Attaching an event target method to a menu link 
document.getElementById("menu-item-332").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
         // checking/unchecking an input element
        document.getElementById("tabfive").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("tabsix").checked = true;
      });
```

CSS

```
.tabs label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tabs label {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs .tab {
  order: 9;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
  display: block;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: please add complete HTML File, so it will help me to debug the questions.
in the current HTML file, there is no <a> tag

Comment: The <a> tag is menu tag